# Setting PATH environment variable in Macbook M1 for AWS amplify error

Tags: amazon-web-services, environment-variables, aws-amplify

I have just installed amplify by doing `npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli`

Now I am trying to `amplify configure` but it is giving me an error: `zsh: permission denied: amplify`

So I used `sudo` in front of it, entered my password, but this time it says `amplify: command not found`

I have a feeling it is likely to do with my PATH environment variable. But I am worried because I am not too familiar with this stuff. All I know is I can see that some of my global packages are installed in  **usr -> local -> lib -> node_modules** and some are installed in **opt -> homebrew -> bin**

I tried putting this command in my `zshrc`: `export PATH="$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin/"` and it does not work. I realized that my `/opt/homebrew/bin` is actually located in `macintoshHD/opt/homebrew/bin`. This means I have to go up twice, because `$PATH` is my `userName`. so I tried putting `export PATH=$PATH:/../../opt/homebrew/bin/` but it still does not work.....

Could someone please help me with this? Just give me the commands for setting my PATH env variable to be correct, and I will do it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your first install despite it's a global install finished with some errors.

try installing it using sudo :

```
sudo npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli
```

and change owner of the local directory :

```
sudo "cd ~youruser && chown youruser ~/.amplify"
```